# Fastest Method to Copy Large Number of Values in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, optimization

Quite simply, I am wondering what the fastest method of copying cell values from one sheet to another is.

Generally, I'll loop through the cells by column and/or row and use a line such as:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i,j).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(y,z).Value
```

In other cases where my ranges are not consecutive rows/columns (e.g. I want to avoid overwriting cells that already contain data) I'll either have a conditional inside the loop, or I'll fill an array(s) with row & column numbers that I want to cycle through, and then cycle through the array elements. For example:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(row1(i),col1(j)).Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(row2(y),col2(z)).Value
```

Would it be faster to define ranges using the cells I want to copy and the destination cells, then do a `Range.Copy` and `Range.Paste` operation? Is it possible to define a range using an array without having to loop through it anyway? Or will it be faster anyway to loop through an array to define a range and then copy-pasting the range instead of equating the cell values by looping?

I feel like it might not be possible to copy and paste ranges like this at all (i.e. they would need to be cells continuous through a rectangular array and pasted into a rectangular array of the same size). That being said, I would think that it's possible to equate the elements of two ranges without looping through each cell and equating the values.

Comment: What stops you from benchmarking this ?

Comment: I'm more curious if there's a general "rule of thumb" or known optimum in all cases, versus the specific case I'm working on. I can easily find out on a case-by-case basis, but it would be beneficial to know if one method is ALWAYS faster than the other (e.g. if one follows Log(n) instead of n^2 for n values to be copied).

Answer (score 10):

For a rectangular block this:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range

    Set r1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:Z1000")
    Set r2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")

    r1.Copy r2
End Sub
```

is pretty quick.

For a **non-contiguous** range on the activesheet, I would use a loop:

```
Sub qwerty2()
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range

    For Each r1 In Selection
        r1.Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range(r1.Address)
    Next r1
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

The range-to-range method does not even require an intermediate array:

```
Sub ytrewq()
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range

    Set r1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:Z1000")
    Set r2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:Z1000")

    r2 = r1
End Sub
```

this is really the same as:

```
ary=r1.Value
r2.value=ary
```

except the `ary` is implicit.

Comment: Would it be quicker to copy/paste than to set the ranges equal?

Comment: @BruceWayne  Setting ranges equal *(assuming the ranges are isomorphic)* might be quicker, but the formatting would not come over..........but maybe that O.K.

Comment: The first example makes sense, I understood how to do that initially; I was just wondering what the speed difference was compared to a loop. I figured it would be faster to do it that way than to loop through each cell.

Comment: For the non-contiguous case, how would you define the ranges if they are originally arrays? That was half of the challenge since I'd think you might have to loop through that anyway. And where is the destination reference in your loop (since both ranges referred to are typed out as "r1"). I also noticed you referenced a Selection without defining one?

Comment: I think I'd go with the "setting ranges equal" route that @BruceWayne suggested if I knew how to define ranges quickly from array values.

Comment: @ma_YYC  See my **EDIT#1.**

Comment: That part makes sense. What I'm asking about is if I have [ary1 = {a1, a2, ... , aN}] and [ary2 = {b1, b2, ... , bN}], where the a's and b's are row numbers, how would I make those ranges that I can then use the [r1 = r2] method? Would the easiest/fastest way be to loop through them to generate cell addresses? The column numbers are known (i.e. static), it's just the rows that are variable (depending on if they are blank rows or not), which is why I can't define the ranges in a contiguous way.

Comment: Maybe you can use his isomorphic approach still?  
`Set rng = Range("A" & ary1(LBound(ary1)) & ":B" & ary1(UBound(ary1))`  
`rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy`

Answer (score 0):

i tried 4 methods, and the NOT obvious (to me) came out:

```
Option Explicit

Sub testCopy_speed()

Dim R1 As Range, r2 As Range
Set R1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:Z1000")
Set r2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("A1:Z1000")

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With


Dim t As Single
Dim i&, data(), Rg As Range
ReDim data(R1.Rows.Count, R1.Columns.Count)

For Each Rg In R1.Cells: Rg = Rnd()*100: Next Rg

R1.ClearContents
R1.ClearFormats

r2.ClearContents
r2.ClearFormats


'For Each Rg In R1.Cells: 'if you do this too often , you'll get an error
'    With Rg
'        .Value2 = Rnd() * 100
'        .Interior.Color = Rnd() * 65535
'        '.Font.Color = Rnd() * 65535
'    End With
'Next Rg


t = Timer

For i = 1 To 100
    'r2.Value2 = R1.Value2 '1,71 sec
    'R1.Copy r2 '0.74 sec  <<<<   Winer , but see NOTE.
    'data = R1.Value2: r2.Value2 = data '1.78 sec
    'For Each Rg In R1.Cells: r2.Cells(Rg.Row, Rg.Column).Value2 = Rg.Value2: Next Rg '54 seconds !!
Next i

Erase data
Set R1 = Nothing
Set r2 = Nothing
Set Rg = Nothing

Debug.Print Timer - t

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End With

End Sub
```

Note : i wasn't happy with these results so i tested some more, and if R1 contains many different formating , the `R1.copy R2` method will take 10 seconds. So in this case `R2=R1`would be better by far (6 times faster).

Answer (score 0):

I found this thread looking to speed up transfer of 72 cells from one sheet to another (a data storage sheet to a data entry sheet).

My code looked like this:

```
t(7)=timer*1000
Dim datasht As Worksheet
Set datasht = WB2.Worksheets("Equipment-Data")
With WB2.Worksheets("Equipment")
 .Range("D2").Value = datasht.Cells(datarow, 1)
 .Range("D3").Value = datasht.Cells(datarow, 2)
 .Range("I7").Value = datasht.Cells(datarow, 3)
 ...
 t(8)=timer*1000     
 ...
 .Range("G51").Value = datasht.Cells(datarow,72)
End With
t(9)=timer*1000
```

*Code typed by hand, please forgive any typos.*

Getting from t(7) to t(9) took around 600ms.  As an aside, I switched from using *Application.WorksheetFunction.Vlookup* 72 times to determining the appropriate row in the data table with a single *datarow=.Cells.Find(...)* and it made no perceivable impact in execution time.

I added a timer in the middle and confirmed that each half was taking roughly 300ms which made sense but wanted to make sure there wasn't a particular cell causing issues.

Since most of the time only 1 or a small handful of cells have changed I added a check to see if the data is different before writing and the Sub now runs in about 4ms.

```
If .Range("D2").Formula <> datasht.Cells(datarow, 1).Formula Then .Range("D2").Value = datasht.Cells(datarow, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Never try to loop over big data set with many rows. Try to copy ranges by columns as much as possible.

```
Dim lRow As Long
lRow = Sheets("Source").Range("A100000").End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("Target").Range("A1:D" & lRow).Value = 
Sheets("Source").Range("G1:J" & lRow).Value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub CopyPaste(rPaste As Range, rCopy As Range, Optional val As Boolean = True)
 Dim p As Long
 Dim r As Long
 Dim c As Long
 Dim aCalculation As XlCalculation
 aCalculation = XlCalc()
 On Error GoTo Finally
Try:
 If rPaste.Count = 1 Then
  r = rPaste.Areas(1).Row - rCopy.Areas(1).Row
  c = rPaste.Areas(1).Column - rCopy.Areas(1).Column
  For p = 1 To rCopy.Areas.Count
   With rCopy.Areas(p)
    Set rPaste = Union(rPaste, Cells(.Row, .Column).Offset(r, c).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count))
   End With
  Next 'p
 End If
 For p = 1 To rPaste.Areas.Count
  With Cells(rCopy.Areas(p).Row, rCopy.Areas(p).Column).Resize(Application.min(rCopy.Areas(p).Rows.Count, rPaste.Areas(p).Rows.Count), _
                                                               Application.min(rCopy.Areas(p).Columns.Count, rPaste.Areas(p).Columns.Count))
   If val Then
    If 1 Then 'faster
     rPaste.Areas(p) = .Value
    Else
     .Copy
     Cells(rPaste.Areas(p).Row, rPaste.Areas(p).Column).PasteSpecial paste:=xlPasteValues
    End If
   Else
    .Copy Destination:= _
    Cells(rPaste.Areas(p).Row, rPaste.Areas(p).Column)
   End If 'val
  End With
 Next 'p
Finally:
 XlCalc aCalculation
End Sub

Function XlCalc(Optional aCalculation As Long = 0) As XlCalculation
 Dim bCutCopyMode As Boolean
 Dim bCleared As Boolean
 bCutCopyMode = Application.CutCopyMode
 XlCalc = Application.Calculation
 Application.EnableEvents = aCalculation <> 0
 Application.ScreenUpdating = aCalculation <> 0
 'assignment to Application.Calculation clears the clipboard
 If aCalculation = 0 Then
  bCleared = XlCalc <> xlCalculationManual
  If bCleared Then Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
 Else
  If aCalculation = xlCalculationAutomatic Then Application.Calculate
  bCleared = XlCalc <> aCalculation
  If bCleared Then Application.Calculation = aCalculation
 End If
 If Not bCleared Then Exit Function
 If Not bCutCopyMode Then Exit Function
 If Selection Is Nothing Then Exit Function
 Selection.Copy 'restore clipboard
End Function
```

Comment: For copy and paste into only visible cells look https://github.com/abakum/PasteInVisible

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Look at [GitHub](https://github.com/abakum/PasteInVisible/blob/main/PasteInVisible.bas#:~:text=Sub%20CopyPaste)

Answer (score 0):

Disabling ScreenUpdating adds 8 ms on my machine
Disabling Calculation adds 6

There is no appreciable difference (in microseconds!) between
.Range(cstrColPreviousPrice & clngFirstRow & ":" & cstrColPreviousPrice & glngLastRow).Value2 = .Range(cstrColPrice & clngFirstRow & ":" & cstrColPrice & glngLastRow).Value2

And

.Range(cstrColPreviousPrice & clngFirstRow & ":" & cstrColPreviousPrice & glngLastRow).Value2 = Application.Transpose(gavarPrice())