# Issue when running Workbooks.Open

Tags: excel, vba

I have a button to which I assigned the following macro:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ActiveSheet.Range("B5:M5").Copy
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Documents\Test.xlsx"
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWorkbook.Close

    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B5:K5").ClearContents

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

When I click the button, I get the error 1004. However, if I run the code line by line (F8), the file opens correctly. I even tried to add "DoEvents" after the Workbooks.Open line, thinking it might be a timing issue, but it doesn't work. The file I'm trying to open is not protected and no message is displayed when trying to open it manually.

Thanks!

Comment: If you add the line `MsgBox Dir("C:\Documents\Test.xlsx") <> ""` does it pop up `True` or `False`?

Comment: @Toddleson It returns "True"

Answer (score 0):

I tried to step through your code, but get an error on the line:

```
Active Sheet.Range("B5:M5").Copy
```

I guess it should have been one word "ActiveSheet" and not "Active Sheet".

We need to make sure that we operate on the correct workbooks and the correct sheets. Because when we use the debugger, then as we click around, the active workbook might change.

I have used the workbooks and sheets that I think you intend to use, and corrected the code.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim Wbk1 As Workbook
    Dim Wbk2 As Workbook
    Dim Sht As Worksheet

    Set Wbk1 = ThisWorkbook
    Wbk1.ActiveSheet.Range("B5:M5").Copy
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set Wbk2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Documents\Test.xlsx")
    Set Sht = Wbk2.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Sht.Range("A" & Sht.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Wbk2.Save
    Wbk2.Close

    Wbk1.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B5:K5").ClearContents

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Please note that you don't need to use the clip-board, to copy data from one sheet to another. See [How to copy data in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36272285/fastest-method-to-copy-large-number-of-values-in-excel-vba) and [Range.Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.copy). When we avoid the use of the clip-board, we don't overwrite what the user may have copied to it:

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim Wbk1 As Workbook, Wbk2 As Workbook
    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    Dim Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range

    Set Wbk1 = ThisWorkbook
    Set Rng1 = Wbk1.ActiveSheet.Range("B5:M5")

    Set Wbk2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Documents\Test.xlsx")
    Set Sht = Wbk2.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set Rng2 = Sht.Range("A" & Sht.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

    Rng1.Copy Rng2

    ' Add code to clear data in the first workbook and save and close
    ' the other workbook here.
End Sub
```

When that is said, please be aware that the bug may have other causes, like a buggy office-plugin, a buggy version of excel or the like, which I have experienced several times. If that is the case, then we need to investigate and experiment more, to solve the bug.

Comment: First of al, thank you for your suggestion. I think this is an intermitent problem. Your code worked for a while, but now I'm getting the same error. It bothers me because this is supposed to be a simple code, yet that particular line gives me lots of trouble. Now, I tried to open that file manually and it tells me it's already open, when in fact isn't. That kind of explains the error, but it makes no sense. I've tried to close and reopen Excel but I get the same message.  For some unknown reason, the file is either open but not visible or there's a problem with the system...

Comment: When you experiment with your code, you might have opened the file without closing it. You can check if excel is running by opening a command prompt and running `tasklist /FI "imagename eq excel.exe"`. You can kill the excel instances by running `taskkill /FI "imagename eq excel.exe" /F`.

Comment: When VBA code works then stops working, throwing strange errors, it may mean that the compile cache of the document has become corrupted. The way to solve this, is to export all code modules (workbook, sheets, modules, forms, classes), then delete them from the workbook and save and close the workbook. Then open the workbook  and import the code again, compile the code (The VBE menu `Debug > Compile`), and then save and close the workbook.

Comment: To delete code from the workbook module and sheets modules, just open the code modules, select all the code and delete it. I always delete all code, save and close, then import all code and save and close, before delivering any macro-enabled office document to a customer.

Comment: @user17433563 thank you very much for your comments, helped a lot!